How to use stored procedure in ExecuteSQLRecord? NiFi 1.16
I have a stored procedure in postgresql that inserts data into a table.
The procedure receives a Json.
Stored procedure:
SELECT public.function_insert_example(
    '{"field1": "1","field2": "Example1","field3": "Red"}'::jsonb
);

The content of the flowfile is as follows:
[
  {
    "field1": "1",
    "field2": "Example1",
    "field3": "Red"
  },
  {
    "field1": "2",
    "field2": "Example2",
    "field3": "Blue"
  }
]

I understand that "Record" type processors are for working on list and array structures.
How to send each json to the stored procedure without using a split?
Also, what should be the query that is entered in the column (SQL select query)
Try performing the native query with an attribute from the stream file.
SELECT public.function_insert_example('${data}'::jsonb);

But the idea is not to use attributes, but directly the data from the flowfile.
